# Outline object (normal scale + stencil mask) three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

For some time, I've been trying to figure out how to do an object selection outline in my game. (So the player can see the object over everything else, on mouse-over)

This is how the result should look:

[image]

The solution I would like to use goes like this:

1. Layer 1: Draw model in regular shading.
2. Layer 2: Draw a copy in red color, scaled along normals using vertex shader.
3. Mask: Draw a black/white flat color of the model to use it as a stencil mask for the second layer, to hide insides and show layer 1.

And here comes the problem. I can't really find any good learning materials about masks. Can I subtract the insides from the outline shape? What am I doing wrong?

I can't figure out how to stack my render passes to make the mask work. :(

**Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/4/)**

```
renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, renderTargetParameters)

composer    = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget)
// composer   = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer)

normal      = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera)
outline     = new THREE.RenderPass(outScene, camera)
mask        = new THREE.MaskPass(maskScene, camera)
// mask.inverse = true
clearMask   = new THREE.ClearMaskPass
copyPass    = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader)
copyPass.renderToScreen = true

composer.addPass(normal)
composer.addPass(outline)
composer.addPass(mask)
composer.addPass(clearMask)
composer.addPass(copyPass)
```

Also I have no idea whether to use render target or renderer for the source of the composer. :( Should I have the first pass in the composer at all? Why do I need the copy pass? So many questions, I know. But there are just not enough resources to learn from, I've been googling for days.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Maybe an alternate approach will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739760/complex-shape-character-outline/21863009#21863009

Comment: @WestLangley Oh, wow. I completely missed this. That looks just like the thing I need. I'll try it out.
I simply can't thank you enough! So glad you are frequenting stack overflow.

Comment: @WestLangley On closer examination, this doesn't help me at all. I would need to copy not only the object to second scene, but also all dynamic lights, which would add a lot of overhead. All to draw the whole object in front of others which isn't even what I wanted in first place.

I really need to draw just the outline which means finding out how the masking works. Or use some kind of a raster filter.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. I'll post the solution.

Comment: See my comment on your posted solution.  This only works in a narrow range of mesh types, it is not a complete solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a js fiddle with working solution. You're welcome. :)

[http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/5/)

Update with only two render passes (credit to WestLangley):
http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/9/

The pieces missing were these:

```
composer.renderTarget1.stencilBuffer = true
composer.renderTarget2.stencilBuffer = true
outline.clear = false
```

Comment: Nice! You do not need 3 cameras (at least in this demo), and the cameras do not need to be added to the scene(s). Also, by assigning quaternions, you can omit updating the rotations of 2 meshes in the render loop. See http://jsfiddle.net/g593q/7/

Comment: @WestLangley Nice! I was just trying to figure out that rotation part. Thanks a lot. :) Now the last thing to solve is bone animation data from one skinned mesh to another.

Comment: Please make a new post if you have a new issue.

Comment: @WestLangley Here is a thread for the new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245748/uniform-vertex-displacement-for-skinned-mesh-shader-animated-outline-three-js

Comment: Here is another, simpler, solution to the original post: http://jsfiddle.net/g593q/8/

Comment: @WestLangley Beautiful :) I tried the depthWrite before but couldn't get it to work. This is awesome, it's going to be much faster. Again, thanks a lot.
With the quaternion rotation it was a pretty stupid mistake on my part, I wasn't asigning it right.

Comment: @WestLangley Ah, now I know where's the problem. I wanted the outline to be visible over everything else. Which I thought would not be possible without layer composing. I've tested it on both and my original solution doesn't work like I wanted either. :(

`Two renderer passes`: http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/12/
`Effect compositor`: http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/14/

Comment: I can solve it by setting the depthWrite false on the occluding mesh. http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/15/
But that would mean I would have to find those first (by raytracing maybe). Doesn't seem ideal. I thought the outline and mask pass can't get affected by other objects that are not rendered in those passes.

Comment: Solved! http://jsfiddle.net/g593q/21/
Really easy actually. I just had to set depthWrite false to the outline material itself.

Comment: The normal around the edge will not properly scale up the model, how to deal with that? http://imgur.com/yFXWlPi

Comment: I guess the mesh have to be connected. No idea how to solve it for submeshes, didn't even know you can have that in threejs.

Comment: This solution ONLY works for meshes that have nice, rounded, connecting faces.  Change your Torus Knot to a BoxGeometry and you'll see that it does not properly find the edges.  The issue is with the shader you wrote, it only offsets the vertex in the direction of the  normal, which leaves a "hole" when you have edges with large degrees of change with each other, like a box has.

Comment: How would you like the outline to look for unconnected meshes? I cant really imagine a use case scenario for that. Please create a new question with explanation, maybe I can help you there. In this question I was only interested in closed meshes.

Answer (score 4):

Now I think I've found a bit simpler solution, from the THREEx library. It pre-scales the mesh so you dont need a realtime shader for it.
http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.geometricglow/examples/geometricglowmesh.html