# Three.js - how to set borders to objects?

Tags: javascript, three.js, border

I have polygon/polyhedron created with three.js? Is it possible to set border width and color for it?
Here is my example code, you may see a figure in it. How to set borders?
May be there are other ways to create polygons?

```html
<html> 
<head> 
 <title>Моё</title> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style>
  body { margin: 0; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
 </style> 
</head> 
<body>
 <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 <script>
 var phi = 0;
 var scene    = new THREE.Scene();
 var camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000 );
 //var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 200, window.innerWidth / 200, window.innerHeight / 200, window.innerHeight / - 200, 0.1, 1000 );
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
 
 var polyhedronShape, polyhedronPts = [], cube, mesh;
 var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
 // CONTROLS
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
 
 polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 0, 60) );
 polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 60, 60) );
 polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 60, 0) );
 
 polyhedronShape = new THREE.Shape( polyhedronPts );

 var extrudeSettings = {amount: 20}; // bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2 , bevelSegments: 5, bevelSize: 8, bevelThickness:5
 
 var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( polyhedronShape, extrudeSettings );

 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00cc00 } ) );
 //mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
 //mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 100 );
 //mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 scene.add( mesh );
 

 camera.position.z = 111;
 //cube.position.x += 2;
 var cam_z = 0.1, cam_max = 9, cam_min = 2;
 function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  controls.update();
  if (Math.random() > 0.2) {
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
   //camera.position.z += cam_z;
  }
 }
 render();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WHat do you mean "you may see a figure in it"? Do you mean you want the edges of your polyhedron highlighted? Or do you want the outline effect described by @Wilt?

Comment: I want to highlight edges

Comment: Was my answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if **[this outline effect](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html)** is what you are looking for, but it is a nice way to put a border around your objects:

**[Here a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183507/outline-object-normal-scale-stencil-mask-three-js)** where you find more examples and a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/g593q/5/)** to fool around with.

It uses some WebGL native shader effect if I am not mistaken it is this part:

```
vertex_shader: [
    "uniform float offset;",
    "void main() {",
        "vec4 pos = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position + normal * offset, 1.0 );",
        "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * pos;",
    "}"
].join("\n"),
```