# THREE.Shape to mimic context.clip()

Tags: three.js, shapes, mask

Using THREE.Shape, I can create holes, but rather than holes, I wish to define a clip mask.

I ONLY want to render the shape within a mask, similar to html's canvas/context `.clip()`

Is there a way to do this using holes or other method?

**EDIT:**

So, more background, I was using canvas to render segments, and imported them into three as planes.

The mouth was 1 canvas, and I was able to clip mask the teeth and tongue onto the black part.

See the whole movie at http://zsenji.com (rendered using the old canvas method)

Anyway, now I'm updating everything to use threejs and no more canvases rendered as planes.

I'm going to try three csg , which can hopefully intersect two geometries.  https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSG.html

Then all I would have to do would be extrude the black of the mouth, and intersect it with the teeth/tongue.  I will update

[image: clip mask]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183507/outline-object-normal-scale-stencil-mask-three-js - use a mask pass given by your shape and render..

Comment: thanks for your comment, i updated my post.  The problem is I don't want pure red color, I need it to be filled with more three js meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It worked.

I used very simple `intersect`, similar to https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG/blob/master/examples.html

It's a little slow and there are still some other problems relating to overlapping paths, but for this issue, this was the fix.

All the different fills you see are three shapes
[image]