# outline shader only threejs

Tags: three.js, shader

based on previous questions: [Outline object (normal scale + stencil mask) three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183507/outline-object-normal-scale-stencil-mask-three-js/23198184#23198184)

I am trying to make a material shader for threejs to render only the contour and not both with the object. Should this be the right reference or is there a more straighforward way to do it?

Comment: There is already an official example for an outline post-processing effect (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_outline). Maybe you can use/adjust it instead of creating a custom one from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the most straightforward solution I could find is from: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html with a slightly scaled marching cube using `side: THREE.BackSide` param in its material.