# Using TransformControls with OutlinePass in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add an OutlinePass described in [outline a 3d object in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341396/outline-a-3d-object-in-three-js/39693948).  I'm using TransformControls to move objects in my scene.  However, whenever I try to outline an object, it looks like the TransformControls are being outlined as well.  This is especially prominent when the hiddenEdgeColor is lighter.

You can see an example where I added a TransformControl to the [OutlinePass demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=out#webgl_postprocessing_outline) provided by THREE.js:

https://jsfiddle.net/ye0e47dv/3/

I added this snippet:

```js
let gizmo = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
scene.add(gizmo);
gizmo.attach(floorMesh);
```

If you select any object other than the ground, you'll see the TransformControls light up.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue using up-to-date TransformControls, OutlinePass (containing the patch mentioned in the answer of @eskubeltz) and THREEjs (v100).

It seems that some recent modifications on the visiblity tags are responsible of this.

To solve this, I tag the TransformControls objects:

```
control = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, domElement);
control.traverse((obj) => { // To be detected correctly by OutlinePass.
  obj.isTransformControls = true;
});
```

.. and fix again the Outline.VisibilityChangeCallBack() function like following:

```
if ( object.isMesh || object.isLine || object.isSprite || object.isTransformControls )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with Lineas and Sprites. To fix this problem, I edited the file outlinePass.js in the line 181 (function VisibilityChangeCallBack)

Original

```
if (( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
```

Edited

```
if (( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) || (object instanceof THREE.Sprite) || (object instanceof THREE.Line)) {
```

I think your problem will be fixed with this change, as I could see in your jsfiddle only the lines of the transformControl are selected, not the cones.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, was facing the same issue with simple sprites added to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

In three version 0.132.2 just add `|| object.isTransformControls` to VisibilityChangeCallBack().
Updated OutlinePass code is here (with three module imports changed). You can use this OutlinePass - https://paste-bin.xyz/6023